# Create HTML buttons like xperia x8 home screen

Tags: android, html, css

So most phone companies have their own twist on the Android UI when they license it for their phones. I like the UI design created by Sony Ericsson for their phones, where they have quarter circles on corners of their home screens.

I am looking to create similar looking buttons for my HTML page. So that my page would have 4 quarter circles in the 4 corners of the screen.

[image: source: pianetacellulare.it]

I am sure this can be solved easily if the problem is understood, and I just couldn't find the right term to search for it. In essence I need something like this using only HTML, CSS and JQuery (below is an image created in Word, the 4 ovals are buttons with dropdown options):

[image]

Also while we are at it, is there any term that Sony uses for its customized UI (for eg. Xperia X8 uses Android 2.1, but its home screen is different than that used by a HTC phone).

Comment: I think Sony's custom UI is called 'Timescape UI'.

Comment: @Rowno Hmmm that's helpful... now the HTMLs..

Comment: _"I am sure this can be solved easily"_ - while I understand what you want to achieve, I do not understand where you did get stuck and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @w4rumy I was stuck in what exactly to call these shapes. Also while css design was coming easily to me, morphing a button into looking something like a semi circle was difficult. Here I was able to provide visual examples, on google I needed to rely on keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to go about this.

If it were me I would just make four divs with fixed position and round the corners, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/KDgLU/2/

```
div.button {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:blue;
    height:50px; width:50px;
}
#topLeft {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
}
#topRight {
    right:0; top:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
}
#botLeft {
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    border-top-right-radius:100%;
}
#botRight {
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    border-top-left-radius:100%;
}
```

Note that you should make the border-radius more cross-browser friendly. You can easily do this with this little tool: http://border-radius.com/

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Turns out I was struggling with Position:fixed all along...but kuods...this is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can style them using CSS.
Here is an assumption of your HTML:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <button id='upper-left-corner'>Messages</button>
```

Now you add the CSS:

```
<style>
#upper-left-corner {
position:absolute;
text-align:left;
left:0;
top:0;
</style>
```

It's pretty close.